# C# override abstract member

Tags: c#, overriding

Heres my code where im tryng to override SettingsFileName member:

```
    public class ProcessorTest: Processor
    {
        public virtual override string SettingsFileName
        {
            get { return @"C:\Settings.xml"; }
        }
    }
```

Heres the class where is the member:

```
    public abstract class Processor
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Implement this property to enable initializing singleton from the correct file path
        /// </summary>
        public abstract string SettingsFileName { get; }
    }
```

But this gives me a error:

```
A member 'ProcessorTest.SettingsFileName' marked as override cannot be marked as new or virtual
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use `override`in the inherited class, not `virtual override`.

`virtual` marks a member as overridable, so it's used in the base class. `override` marks a member as overriding someone overridable. `abstract` implies `virtual`.

Comment: What if I want to inherit from the child class, and override its override?

Comment: @ORcoder That should work, as an override method is still virtual and could be overridden. To forbid further overriding an override method, it has to be declared as 'sealed override'.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, and my code works.

Answer (score 4):

remove the virtual here

```
public class ProcessorTest: Processor
{
    public override string SettingsFileName
    {
        get { return @"C:\Settings.xml"; }
    }
}
```

keywords can not be used together

Answer (score 0):

As it **overrides** an abstract Property, `SettingsFileName` cannot be virtual.

> You cannot use the modifiers new, static, virtual, or abstract to
>   modify an override method.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more information on `override` and [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on `abstract`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `virtual` keyword in `ProcessorTest`.

`override` means "override virtual function", so there is no need to write it again.